# Flutter web:How to put a space in a text field without using AltGr?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

That's my problem, when I'm trying to type a space in my release flutter web build and it doesn't do anything and only works if its typed with AltGr pressed. Does anyone have a clue about this or is this a bug with the build process?
I've tried putting the TextField inside a form and outside but no difference is made.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed switching to beta channel, luckily everything should be good on master